# Scala - Constructs map from two lists at initialization

Tags: scala, dictionary, initialization

I'm  new in Scala programming.

I would like to have this kind of immutable map :

```
Map[ (Int,Int), (List[BoolVar]) ]
```

From these two lists :

```
val courseName = List("Course1","Course2")
val serieName = List("Serie1","Serie2")
```

My goal :

```
Map[0][0] // List[BoolVar] for "Course1""Serie1"
Map[0][0](0) // a BoolVar from "Course1""Serie1" List
....
```

I tried this but the syntax is false :

```
val test = Map[ (Int,Int), (List[BoolVar]) ](
      for (course <- List.range(0,courseName.length) )
      for( serie <- List.range(0,serieName.length) ) 
      yield (course,serie) -> 
          for (indice <- List.range(0, 48))
          yield BoolVar( courseName(course) + " - " + serieName(serie) )  
);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for ?? Just a few minor changes.
But it will use round brackets

```
val courseName = List("Course1","Course2")
val serieName = List("Serie1","Serie2")

 val m = {
   for {
course <- List.range(0,courseName.length) 
    serie <- List.range(0,serieName.length) 
   } yield (course, serie) -> {
    for (indice <- List.range(0, 48))
            yield BoolVar( courseName(course) + " - " + serieName(serie) )   
    }
}.toMap

println( m )
```

Comment: Take your time. ask question if something not clean. mark answered if ok:)

Comment: Just for the reference: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/sequence-comprehensions.html

Comment: I tried and it works. Thanks for show me how to use toMap with complex key , value map :)

Comment: If you have time. Try reduce this to simple code by introducing abstract type.

Comment: i would like to notify you that the last yield was supposed to put a BoolVar ^^. It can be strange for anyone to see that

Comment: What scala version are you using? can't find BoolVar definition

Comment: So, feel free to change it to BoolVar. Its look like you have this type defined somewhere.

Comment: I am using JaCop : http://jacopguide.osolpro.com/guideJaCoP.html (for a constraint programming projet).

Comment: Just replace last yield with:  yield BoolVar( courseName(course) + " - " + serieName(serie) )